# Rotate a random-angled Canvas object around its center to follow the direction of mousemove

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

Following a previous answered question [Rotate a Canvas object around its center following mousemove event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914999/how-to-rotate-a-canvas-object-around-its-center-following-mouse-move-event/37915102?noredirect=1#comment63290836_37915102), I am bogged down by another challenge when writing my code. I want to have an circle that has a smaller colored/black circle inside. The black circle's center is not at the center of the big circle but shifts a little.

Suppose my object appears at a random angle on canvas, when I move my mouse on canvas, I wish that the black circle part of the big circle would be always facing my mouse direction, which I don't know how to achieve after several hours of tinkering with my code.

Here is my code (also see [Fiddle:random-angled object rotate around center on mousemove](https://jsfiddle.net/hg1k8ywc/)):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

class Circle {
    constructor(options) {
    this.cx = options.x;
    this.cy = options.y;
    this.radius = options.radius;
    this.color = options.color;
    this.angle = options.angle;
    this.toAngle = this.angle;

    this.binding();
  }

  binding() {
    const self = this;
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        self.update(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    });
  }

  update(nx, ny) {
    this.toAngle = Math.atan2(ny - this.cy, nx - this.cx);
  }

  render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.lineWidth = 1;

        ctx.translate(this.cx, this.cy);
        if (this.toAngle !== this.angle) {
      ctx.rotate(this.toAngle - this.angle);
    }

        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);



        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.arc(0, this.radius / 2, this.radius / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

var rotatingCircle = new Circle({
    x: 340,
  y: 250,
  radius: 40,
  color: 'black',
  angle: Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI
});

function animate() {
    rotatingCircle.render();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

**Update with solution:**

After reading @K3N and @markE's answers I have come up a solution which fit in my code, using `setTransform` method. Though I use `canvas.getBoundingClientRect()` I can't subtract the left and the top from `clientX` and `clientY` otherwise my code will fail.

Here is the solution I currently implement:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

class Circle {
    constructor(options) {
    this.cx = options.x;
    this.cy = options.y;
    this.radius = options.radius;
    this.color = options.color;

    this.angle = options.angle;

    this.binding();
  }

  binding() {
    const self = this;
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      self.calculateAngle(e);
    });
  }

  calculateAngle(e) {
    if (!e) return;
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        // mx = parseInt(e.clientX - rect.left),
        // my = parseInt(e.clientY - rect.top),
        vx = e.clientX - this.cx,
        vy = e.clientY - this.cy;
    this.angle = Math.atan2(vy, vx);

  }

  renderEye() {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, this.cx, this.cy);

    ctx.rotate(this.angle);

    let eyeRadius = this.radius / 3;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.radius / 2, 0, eyeRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

  }

  render() {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.cx, this.cy, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#09f';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.stroke();

    this.renderMessage();
    this.renderEye();

  }

  renderMessage() {
    ctx.font = "18px serif";
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText('Angle: ' + this.angle, 30, canvas.height - 40);
  }
}

var rotatingCircle = new Circle({
    x: 360,
  y: 300,
  radius: 40,
  color: 'black',
  angle: Math.random() * Math.PI * 2
});

function animate() {
    rotatingCircle.render();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

Comment: To get the angle between two points use the function Math.atan2 . For example points p1, p2 find the direction from p1 to p2. 'var direction = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);` Note that for this function y must come first to match the canvas orientation default.

Comment: @Blindman67 I see. How is it usually achieved? Should I rotate the canvas at the beginning or adjust the x and y for the orientation?

Comment: You should do it on every render.